# Use GIT - VC software in my workflow from staging machine to production

Tags: wordpress, git, ubuntu

I'm starting using GIT and VC software in order to make my workflow smooth and get the advantages of version control in my projects.

Talking about WordPress, I usually code in this computer of mine, and install and start each project into a Ubuntu - LEMP environment I got on another computer of my LAN, a sort of **really fast staging machine** - I never loved MAMP and prefer to have a real web server to play with.

Each project of mines is reachable via 1.1.1.1/project

When it's time to show it, I transfer the whole on the hosting provider server, so that it is reachable via www.project.com

Is it feasible - and how - to use GIT / Bitbucket in order to do the following?

- keep coding on my local computer
- push changes on my local web server, for staging purposes (sort of
  local branch)
- push the most important changes - and final as well - on the remote production server
  (sort of remote master)

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Please, be patient with my noobish misuse of version control terminology.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first two points are normal git operations with a remote repository (so read a git tutorial). The last is a common DevOps approach: merge into a specific branch and push triggers a server update: again plenty of tutorials around.

Comment: Thank you so much @Richard

Yet on my way with GIT tutorials, I'm going to have a look for the other approach. Is this tool useful? 
https://ftploy.com/
a friend of mine just suggested it